# How to chnage permissin in hpsted chef

Tags: chef-infra, infrastructure

In hosted chef, I have created new validator key and chef-client got communicated successfully. But while uploading cookbook I am facing the below problem. Even I couldn't able to list nodes in the same node.

> root@osboxes:/etc/chef-server# knife cookbook upload sample --config
>   ./knife.rb  \Uploading sample       [0.1.0] ERROR: You authenticated
>   successfully to https://api.chef.io/organizations/samsam as naganode
>   but you are not authorized for this action Response:  missing create
>   permission

How change the permission ? chef-clt is not available for Hosted Chef.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up your knife.rb with your username (`node_name`) and key from your user, not as a node. You can reset your user key from your Hosted Chef account preferences.